# Non-zero indexed array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio-2015

I have created a .NET library compiled by LabVIEW which has a function that takes an array of numbers and a multiplicand. This function will return an array where each number has been multiplied with the multiplicand. When the function is called in C#, it turns out that the function takes a non-zero indexed array (`double[*]`) and an `int` as the parameters and return another non-zero indexed array.

I'm able to create a non-zero indexed array with C#'s `Array.CreateInstance()` method. However I'm not able to pass this array into the function since the data type required is `double[*]`.

From the research on the internet, it seems like .NET does not support non-zero indexed array type. I've tried to find a way to modify the LabVIEW program to generate the function that takes in a zero-indexed array without avail.

Any advice on how I can go around this issue?

**Update 1**

LabVIEW block diagram
[image: LabVIEW block diagram]

C# Program

```
const int Length = 5;
const int LowerBound = 1;
// Instanstiate a non-zero indexed array. The array is one-dimensional and
// has size specified by Length and lower bound specified by LowerBound.
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), new int[] { Length }, new int[] { LowerBound });
// Initialize the array.
for (int i = numbers.GetLowerBound(0); i <= numbers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    numbers.SetValue(i, i);
}

var variable = LabVIEWExports.Multiply(numbers, 2); // This is invalid as numbers is not typed double[*].
Console.ReadKey();
```

Signature of the LabVIEW function in C#

[image]

**Update 2**

Tried to use C#'s Reflection to call the LabVIEW function with the following codes, but encounter `TargetInvocationException`.

```
const int Length = 5;
const int LowerBound = 1;
const string methodName = "MultiplyArray";
const string path = @"C:\";

Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), new int[] { Length }, new int[] { LowerBound });
for (int i = numbers.GetLowerBound(0); i <= numbers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    numbers.SetValue(i, i);
}

Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(path + "LabVIEW.Interop.dll");
Type type = asm.GetType("LabVIEW.Interop.LabVIEWInteropExports");

if (type != null)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);

    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        object result = methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, new object[] { array, multiplicand }); // Throw exception.
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Inner exception message

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[*]' to type 'System.Double[]'.`

Inner exception stack trace

`at NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.Interop.DataMarshal.InitMarshalArrayIn(IntPtr data, Array array, Marshal1DArray val)
at LabVIEW.Interop.LabVIEWInteropExports.MultiplyArray(Double[*] input__32Array, Int32 numeric)`

It seems like at some point of the execution, the program tries to marshal the type `double[*]` to `double[]` with `InitMarshalArrayIn()` function in the assembly that comes with LabVIEW.

Comment: @Nishat: please don't use code blocks for non-code...

Comment: .NET does support arrays that are non-zero indexes. C# has no syntax to write such a type but you can create it using Array.Create* and pass it using reflection.

Comment: Did you mean double*[]? What do you mean by double[*]?

Comment: Check the parameter ElementType you can do typeof(yourRequiredType)

Comment: @MathuSumMut, `double[*]` is a **non-zero indexed array** of type `double`. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6f84f77-1a09-4dd9-a2af-eb3a54e9c7bc/array-question-single-dimension-array-with-nonzero-lower-bound?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: I would like to replicate the code of the question. From where did you obtain the assembly containing the LabVIEWExports class?

Comment: @MathuSumMut, the assembly containing the LabVIEWExports class is my own writing. The block diagram is exactly the screen shoot on my updated question. It is compiled as .NET Interop assembly with LabVIEW 2015.

Comment: If so, I suggest you rewrite LabVIEWExports to use zero-based arrays, but if that is not possible, try using the "Array" base class as the type of the parameters instead of the double[*] type which is barely supported by the C# syntax. In other words, leave Multiply() content as is, simply change the header to: Array Multiply(Array numbers, int multiplicant), and simply cast the method body accordingly.

Comment: You can only use zero-based arrays with LabVIEW, there shouldn't be a need for this.

Comment: I would like this question rewritten to remove the LabVIEW aspect. There's nothing specific to LV about this question, and it is a useful question to ask, "How can C# invoke a library that has a non-zero-indexed array in its signature?" Yes, LV created that signature, but that's not relevant to the question at hand. It could've been any .NET compiler that created the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether i should put this as answer or not, but here it goes:

It happens that this is an issue related to Visual Studio 2015 as I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1. See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1668248/net-interop-method-is-not-supported-by-the-language) and [this](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/LabView-Net-Interop-and-Arrays/td-p/3183711/highlight/true/page/2) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

**.NET does support** arrays that are non-zero indexes. **C# has no syntax** to write such a type but you can create it using `Array.CreateInstance`.

Next, **use reflection to call** `LabVIEWExports.Multiply` and pass the array that you created.

Comment: Tried using reflection to call `LabVIEWExports.Multiply` (see Update 2 in the question), but encounter exception. I'm not too sure whether I'm doing it wrong, or it just simply because of LabVIEW itself does not support the casting from `double[*]` to `double[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Will it work if you use `dynamic` (rather than resorting to reflection), as in the last line of:

```
const int Length = 5;
const int LowerBound = 1;
// Instanstiate a non-zero indexed array. The array is one-dimensional and
// has size specified by Length and lower bound specified by LowerBound.
var numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), new int[] { Length }, new int[] { LowerBound });
// Initialize the array.
for (int i = numbers.GetLowerBound(0); i <= numbers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    numbers.SetValue(i, i);
}

var variable = (Array)LabVIEWExports.Multiply((dynamic)numbers, 2);
```

The variable `numbers` has compile-time type `Array` to C# since C# does not have a syntax for `double[*]`. But maybe it will be OK with `dynamic` where the actual type of `numbers` at run-time should be correct, so maybe late binding to the correct method will work?

Comment: Does not work for me. It throws `System.InvalidCastException` during runtime.

Comment: @NoctisTong OK. I do not have VS2015 with its new C# compiler, and I do not have CLR version 4.6, but maybe it is the same problem as you see when you use reflection (update 2 in your question)? From the pages you link I get the impression that it used to work with VS2013 etc.

Comment: @Jeppee, I've tried to call the same assembly generated by the LabVIEW from VS 2010 and it works. Seems like it is a VS issue rather than a LabVIEW issue.

Comment: @NoctisTong Was it on the same machine? I ask because it is interesting to know if it is a problem with the IL generated by the C# compiler, or a problem with the CLR (runtime). In the first case, it could be the C# compiler which outputs some wrong IL code forcing a check that a `double[*]` (otherwise known as `double[...]`) cannot pass. In the second case, it could be a bug in the version 4.6 runtime. Have you tried changing the C# target version to C# 5.0 within Visual Studio 2015, as in [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St)?

Comment: yes it is on the same machine. Changing the C# target version to C# 3.0, C# 4.0, and C# 5.0 does not solve the issue.

Comment: @NoctisTong My hypothesis, then, is that this is a bug in the C# compiler of VS2015 which does not go away even if we target earlier C# versions (and still use the VS2015 C# compiler). You could open `ildasm` and open the EXE/DLL produced by VS2015, browse to the method in question, and read the IL to see if it mentions `float64[]` or similar (which will crash since the instance is not a "vector" `float64[]` but instead a "multi-dimensional array of rank one" `float64[...]`).